# Regex pattern for parsing

Tags: java, regex, string, java.util.scanner

I need a pattern that matches each of the following:

- A nonwhitespace string of symbols other than (`:=#\`) followed by `:` followed by one more strings on nonwhitespace symbols other than (`:=#\`)  OR
- a blank or tab followed by 1 or more non-whitespace characters OR
- a # followed by anything OR
- a line consisting of one or more spaces or tabs OR
- a catchall for things not caught before.

My current pattern is as follows:
`^([\\S&&[^\\n:=#\\\\]]+):([[\\s&&[^\\n]][\\S&&[^\\n=:#\\\\]]*]*)|^[ \\t](\\S[\\s\\S&&[^\\n]]*)|(^#[\\s\\S&&[^\n]]+)|^([\\s&&[^\\n\\x0B\\f\\r]]+)|([[\\s\\S]&&[^\\n]]+)`

I am using it with a Scanner using findwithinhorizon(*this Pattern*, 0)

In the following block inp is a Scanner of a buffered and _pat is the pattern above.
I've had a problem with strings being assigned to the wrong matching groups.

EX:

```
bob: cat dog
 meow
```

Running this in this scanner I get an empty string after calling .split(`\\s+`) on matching group 2 (" cat dog") and "meow" is matched by group 6 (my error group) instead of group 3.

```
    BufferedReader buf =
            new BufferedReader(new FileReader(makeFile));
    Scanner inp = new Scanner(buf);


    while (inp.findWithinHorizon(_pat, 0) != null) {
        int i = 1;
        MatchResult mat = inp.match();
        for (; i <= TOTAL_VALS; i++) {
            if (mat.group(i) != null) {
                break;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

This regex will parse a line into appropriate groups:

```
([^\s:=#\\]+\s*:\s*(?:[^\s:=#\\]+\s*))|([ \t]\S+)|(#.*)|(\s*)|(.*)
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

Note that your first condition does not actually match `bob: cat dog`. The condition should something like:

- A nonwhitespace string of symbols other than `:=#\` optionally followed by whitespace, followed by `:` optionally followed by whitespace, followed by one more strings of nonwhitespace symbols other than (:=#) separated with whitespace OR

---

Sample usage:

```
String regex = "([^\\s:=#\\\\]+\\s*:\\s*(?:[^\\s:=#\\\\]+\\s*)+)|([ \t]\\S+)|(#.*)|(\\s*)|(.*)";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex);
for (String line : lines) {
    Matcher m = p.matcher(line);
    m.matches();
    for(int i=1;i<m.groupCount();i++) {
        System.out.println(i+": "+m.group(i));
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

For your input data:

```
bob: cat dog
 meow
```

the output will be

```
1: bob: cat dog
2: null
3: null
4: null

1: null
2:  meow
3: null
4: null
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at a little chunk of your regular expression (removing extra escapes)

```
[\S&&[^\n:=#\\]]+
```

This doesn't really make sense in regex syntax. I'm guessing from your description that this part of the pattern is supposed to mean "a sequence of characters that are not whitespace, and also are not newlines or `:=#\`."  This is how you'd write a regex pattern for that:

```
[^\s:=#\\]+
```

i.e. "one or more characters that are not whitespace, `:`, `=`, `#` or `\`.

So taking your requirements one at a time:

- A nonwhitespace string of symbols other than (`:=#\`) followed by `:` followed by one more strings on nonwhitespace symbols other than (`:=#\`)  OR

  ```
  [^\s:=#\\]+:[^\s:=#\\]
  ```
- a blank or tab followed by 1 or more non-whitespace characters OR

  ```
  [ \t]\S+
  ```
- a # followed by anything OR

  ```
  #.*
  ```
- a line consisting of one or more spaces or tabs.

  ```
  [ \t]+
  ```

Putting them all together:

```
^([^\s:=#\\]+:[^\s:=#\\]|[ \t]\S+|#.*|[ \t]+)$
```

and restoring the extra escape characters so it can be put in a double-quoted string:

```
^([^\\s:=#\\\\]+:[^\\s:=#\\\\]|[ \\t]\\S+|#.*|[ \\t]+)$
```

I have left out the "catchall" requirement, since it's not clear to me why it would be useful: a regex like `something|something else|a third thing|.*` is guaranteed to match any string, and might as well be replaced by `.*` for simplicity.

Comment: Thank you!
I think I may have messed up the specification in the first requirement though I meant to say a : followed by zero or more space separated, non-whitespace strings. I'm guessing that would look like this?
[^\s:=#\\]+:[^\s:=#\\]*

Comment: I was also wondering if placing parenthesis throughout to set up capture groups as follows would have any ill effect?
^(([^\\s:=#\\\\]+):([^\\s:=#\\\\]*)|([ \\t]\\S+)|(#.*)|([ \\t]+)|(.*))$

Comment: A series of non-whitespaces strings that are separated by whitespace just means a bunch of any characters. :-)  So you could just drop the `\s` entirely from the second half of the string and get `[^\s:=#\]+:[^:=#\]*`.